# What is the performance difference between using like vs charindex in select statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In a select statement I can write:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COL1 LIKE '%XYZ%'
```

The same can be achieved using:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('XYZ', COL1) != 0
```

What is the performance difference between these approaches?

Comment: Um, try it and see? Inspect the execution plan of them both together and see what you get.

Comment: About the same TBH. If your first query was `LIKE 'XYZ%'` that would be different

Comment: Trying to find binary choices, determine a single "best" between them and then ignore the other is *not* a good strategy for writing code that performs well. Set goals, write the most straightforward code that is correct, measure. Only at that point, if the performance is inadequate, should you start looking for the actual bottlenecks and alternative approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [SQL Server docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), `CHARINDEX` will find the index of the *first* occurrence of the first parameter substring.  As for `LIKE` it is highly likely that it is smart enough to stop searching as soon as it finds a match.  Therefore, I would expect the performance of both of your queries to be roughly the same.  As for which version to use, the `LIKE` expression can handle more complexity than just substring matches, so you might choose that version if you expect the logic could get more complex later on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this has been answered but it's worth noting that you can create a test harness and see for yourself. I created a 1,000,000 row test; first against a shorter string then against a longer one.

```
SELECT TOP(1000000) SomeCol = NEWID()
INTO #t
FROM sys.all_columns, sys.all_columns a;

DECLARE @x INT, @st DATETIME = GETDATE();
  SELECT @x = COUNT(*) FROM #t AS t WHERE t.SomeCol LIKE '%-1234%'
PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 5

DECLARE @x INT, @st DATETIME = GETDATE();
SELECT @x = COUNT(*) FROM #t AS t WHERE CHARINDEX('-1234',t.SomeCol)>0
PRINT DATEDIFF(MS,@st,GETDATE());
GO 5
```

The performance was relatively the same:

```
Beginning execution loop
586
510
530
530
597
Batch execution completed 5 times.
Beginning execution loop
537
606
547
580
607
Batch execution completed 5 times.
```

The execution plans are similar but it would appear that the LIKE query is a smidgen better based on the 49/51% work estimation but this is based on inaccurate cardinality estimations.

[image]

Now if I replace the values with longer strings...

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t;

SELECT TOP(1000000) SomeCol = CONCAT(REPLICATE('x',100),NEWID(),NEWID(),NEWID())
INTO #t
FROM sys.all_columns, sys.all_columns a;
```

... and run the same test both queries actually speed up:

```
Beginning execution loop
350
363
364
370
363
Batch execution completed 5 times.
Beginning execution loop
370
370
376
380
380
Batch execution completed 5 times.
```

The improvement is due to both queries getting parallel execution plans (multiple CPU's doing the work.)

[image]

It's interesting to note that the plans are slightly different - the optimizer choosing a Stream Aggregate operator whereas the CHARINDEX solution uses a Hash Match aggregate. Thought the performance is the same, this still serves as an interesting example of how to manipulate the optimizer's behavior.